# Prevent GitHub Write role from approving PRs

Tags: github

I manage a GitHub organization in which users submit PRs, receive approvals from other users, then merge their own PRs into the main branch.

However, I'd like approval reviews to be granted not by anyone with the Write role, but rather by higher-ups with the Maintainer role. Unfortunately, the default Write role grants users the ability to submit approving reviews, so, at present, all users with the Write role can approve PRs.

Is there any way to prevent users with the Write role from submitting approving reviews?

- I've tried creating a custom role, but it doesn't seem that it's possible to create a custom role with permission to create branches and commit changes to those branches but not to approve PRs.
- The "Code review limits" feature in a repo's "Moderation options" doesn't work either, as those with Write access fall within the limitation.
- Additionally, many of the repos in the organization are private, and Moderation options aren't available for private repos.

Does anyone know of an option or solution that could prevent users with the Write role from approving PRs, leaving it to Maintainers and Admins to approve them?

Comment: You might be able to ask this at [webapps.se] or [su] or because Github is a tool for programmers, at [so].

Comment: You may want to look at GitHub's CODEOWNER feature.